# Call a Qt function from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have a Qt project with a Webview which is loading a HTML file which is Javascriptfiles.  Now I want to call a function on Qt side via JavaScript.

So, having the following Qt function:

```
void MainWIndow::myFunction(angle)
{
    qDebug() << angle;
}
```

I want to call it from JavaScript side:

```
function angleChanged(angle){
    Qt.MainWIndow::myFunction(angle);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Qt` is your `JavaScriptWindowObject`, you should use:

In your Qt code behind (`MainWIndow` class):

`MainWIndow.h` file:

```
public slots:
    void populateJavaScriptWindowObject();
    void myFunction(int angle);
```

`MainWIndow.cpp`file:

```
//in constructor
connect(ui->webView->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
         this, SLOT(populateJavaScriptWindowObject()));

//in populateJavaScriptWindowObject SLOT
void MainWindow::populateJavaScriptWindowObject()
{
    QWebFrame *frame = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame();
    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Qt", this);
}
```

In your Javascript code:

```
function angleChanged(angle) {
    Qt.myFunction(angle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.How I can make QT to JavaScriptWindowObject

Comment: using `addToJavaScriptWindowObject()` method in `populateJavaScriptWindowObject()`.

Comment: Thx will try it soon as possible